# BASH: Loop cut columns from each csv to new csv

Tags: bash, csv, git-bash

I have a number of .csv files all with the same structure of 22 columns. I only require columns 5,14 and 15 so use:

```
$ cut -d, -f5,14,1 original.csv > new_original.csv
```

However I will soon have a number of csv coming in daily and need to use a loop function to perform this on each csv file, and add a prefix "new_"for example to the file name. Alternatively I don't mind -i editing in place.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the following in the directory that contains the csv files.

```
for file in *.csv
do
  cut -d, -f5,14,1 "$file" > "new_$file.csv"
done
```

This will loop over each of them, perform the filtering and output to the same name prefixed with `new_`.

Comment: Cheers
I will tackle loops at a later date it seems